# Error Hibernate Spring: Connection refused

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm having this error when I'm trying to run my code.

My spring configuration class:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.math"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<context:annotation-config />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/game/**" location="/game/" />

<import resource="classpath:*.xml"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</bean>
```

My hibernate configuration xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mathgame</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>

    <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>

    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!--property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property-->

    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <mapping class="com.math.pojo.EntityUser"></mapping>
    <mapping class="com.math.pojo.EntityAnswer"></mapping>
    <mapping class="com.math.pojo.EntityGame"></mapping>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And my persistence xml:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mathgame" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.math.pojo" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    <!--property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="connection.pool_size">5</prop>
        </props>
    </property-->
</bean>

<!--bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="namingStrategy" ref="namingStrategy" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean-->

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="namingStrategy" class="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
```

And my connection factory class:

```
public class ConnectionFactory {

@Autowired
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static Session getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory.openSession();
}
```

}

The error:

> org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: Detalhado: 00410001: Connection failure:
>   socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: localhost; port: 3700  vmcid:
>   OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No     at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.connectFailure(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:253)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:276)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ContactInfoImpl.createConnection(ContactInfoImpl.java:129)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:243)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.request(ClientDelegateImpl.java:227)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.is_a(ClientDelegateImpl.java:392)
>     at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._is_a(ObjectImpl.java:130)     at
>   org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextHelper.narrow(NamingContextHelper.java:69)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext$ProviderCacheKey.getNameService(SerialContext.java:1205)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:393)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:329)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:477)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)  at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.lookup(JndiLocatorDelegate.java:38)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:77)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.lookup(JndiLocatorDelegate.java:33)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource.getProperty(JndiPropertySource.java:82)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:59)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:427)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.LiveBeansView.registerApplicationContext(LiveBeansView.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:951)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:59)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:313)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused: connect   at
>   org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:344)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:250)
>     ... 61 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
>   connect   at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:465)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:457)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:670)  at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.misc.ORBUtility.openSocketChannel(ORBUtility.java:110)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:329)
>     ... 62 more Mai 24, 2014 5:32:32 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
>   buildAutowiringMetadata Advertência: Autowired annotation is not
>   supported on static fields: private static
>   org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.math.dao.HibernateTest.sessionFactory

I tried put the hibernate configurations only in the persistence.xml and put in the hibernate configuration xml. The both throw me this exception. It the code it is possible to see the comment bloks.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are giving wrong credentials to your MYSQL database. Check it once...
And also check whether u gave the mysqlconnector.jar from your file system